# Separate templates for flag links on views and node page

Tags: views, theming, flags

I have a flag called bookmark. The link to this flag is available on a View and the node page.

On the view, I would like this flag link to only display as an icon as the link.

On the node page, I would like this flag link to include an icon and some text (like  Add to bookmarks")

When I create a custom template for it, like flag--bookmark.html.twig, this template alters the flag link in both (all) spots where the flag link is included.

Is there a way to have separate templates for the flag link when rendering in a view vs as a field in a node?